# "Wherever I go you get shops that offer materials..."

Tags: word-usage, british-english

I spot this sentence in a passage in a grammar book, which is written by Longman but I could not figure out how the word **get** was used grammatically? As far as I know we can **get to** somewhere. Does it have something to do with street British English?

Here is the full sentence :

> Wherever I go you get shops that offer materials and products from
>   Africa and from Afghanistan or from central and eastern Europe and it
>   seems almost as if you one hardly needs to travel any more because the
>   world has come in on us.

http://picosong.com/2xMt

Comment: that has to be 'wherever'...

Comment: The sample sentence reads like a mock sentence with multiple choice answers, but you (Murat) transcribed all the choices/options.

Comment: In this particular context, get could be used almost interchangeably with 'see' or 'observe'

Comment: @Gary sorry I did not get your point, thanks.

Comment: "... as if you one hardly..." or "... as if one hardly..."? Sounds fishy to me!

Comment: get could be swapped for 'find'

Comment: It's a clumsy example, which I think *must* have been incorrectly transcribed (if, as OP says, it came from a Longman grammar book). Native speakers would be highly unlikely to switch between ***I*** and "generic" ***you*** within the first four words of a statement.

Comment: @Murat as FumbleFingers stated, the example doe snot sound right- not even something a non-native speaker would say. Is it possible that you can take a picture of the page and upload it or can you cite the book, page number, etc so that we can look it up?

Comment: @Gary you can listen the audio now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what she meant. Also, the transcription is correct, but it is transcribed from someone speaking. In that context, I don;t expect sentence construction, et al, to be standard.

[image]

Comment: "Those arrows were brought to you by CoreDraw. CorelDraw. Providing nice arrows for over 30 years." :)